# Formula Field - trying to capture a product name via the record type

Tags: formula, reporting

I am trying to build a report that shows the total sales for each product but I need to capture the product name which can be derived from the record type. Some of the record type values need to fall into one value. For example:

[image]

Mobile and Additional-Mobile need to fall under a value called "mobile".

I understand that I will need to add a formula field to the opportunities to capture this but I am unsure how to go about it. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a formula field that outputs the 'category' your record belongs to, in text form.

In order to do so, create a formula field of type 'text'.

Then create a function that outputs some piece of text based on the recordtype name of that record.

In order to decide between the different categories, you could use an IF statement or a CASE. Since CASE is slightly clearer in terms of syntax, I'll use that as an example:

```
CASE( RecordType.DeveloperName ,
'IT Services','IT Services',
'Mobile','Mobile',
'Additional - Mobile','Mobile',
'None')
```

Note that the example doesn't contain all values, but you know what I mean. Basically you map every 'input' to an 'output' value, and if it doesn't need to change, you put the same value twice.

You could also create a more condense version, only containing the ones that need to change (in this example only additional-mobile). And as the default outcome (the last parameter) put the recordtype developername, without applying any mapping:

```
CASE( RecordType.DeveloperName ,
'Additional - Mobile','Mobile',
RecordType.DeveloperName)
```

Another way of writing this could be using an IF statement:

```
IF( RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Additional - Mobile','Mobile',  RecordType.DeveloperName)
```

If there's only 1 category that needs a mapping, this works fine. As soon as you have more, the 'IF' syntax can get confusing.

> NOTE: I'm using Recordtype.DeveloperName and not Recordtype.Name. The
> reason for this is that Recordtype.Name might be changed when an
> admins decides to change the 'Label' of a recordtype. The
> DeveloperName, however, will have less change of being changed as it
> is clear that is could be referenced in code and other logic, such as
> formula fields.

Comment: awesome Guy thanks for this I will give this a go and see if it works. Thanks so much for the detail!